# Reacting to double tap on a touch screen

Tags: wpf, multi-touch, double-click, touchscreen

I develop a WPF application that will target a Windows 7 machine. The machine is equipped with a touch screen monitor. Since there are severe restrictions for space, the user does not want to use a mouse so the entire GUI will be controlled via taps on the screen. Tapping buttons is equivalent with clicking them. Similarly, clicking an item into a data grid is similar to tapping it. However, if I want to drill down and see details, I need to double-click on the item and I can handle DataGrid's MouseAction LeftDoubleClick event. Tapping twice on the item though is not the same. Of course, I can add a button "See Details" on the form and tap it once an item is selected. Before I do that, I just want to know if there is a way to handle the "double-tap on the touchscreen" event? Is there a way to transform that into the LeftDoubleClick event?

TIA,
Eddie